# Visual Representation of Geometric Derivative

Tags: derivatives, visualization

The geometric derivative is another type of derivative (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_calculus). My question is, is there a way to understand this visually in the same way that one can understand the standard derivative as the slope of the tangent curve?

Edit: I would prefer a visualization on standard cartesian coordinates if available. If not, I guess "exponential paper" will do.

Comment: Graph the function on log paper?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Are you sure that that's right?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. But I think that's what you should be thinking about. It should be logarithmic in the $y$-direction, not the $x$. Or maybe anti-logarithmic. I honestly haven't thought about it.